# an excel filter

Tags: java

I have a program in which I take a input from a cvs file and store them into a ArrayList of ArrayList. And I can sort them according to column but now I want to create like a filter so if a file has bunch of student age and birthday. I would like to display only certain age and may be birthdays from june to july. What do you guys think would be the best approach for this ?

Answer (score 0):

I've used [lambdaj](http://code.google.com/p/lambdaj/).

Take a look at sample :

```
List<Person> sortedByAgePersons = new ArrayList<Person>(persons);
Collections.sort(sortedByAgePersons, new Comparator<Person>() {
        public int compare(Person p1, Person p2) {
           return Integer.valueOf(p1.getAge()).compareTo(p2.getAge());
        }
});
```